# IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory while accessing an Excel file

Tags: python, vba, excel, cmd

I am working on a VBA code which calls a python script saved at desktop. This is my piece of VBA code.

```
Shell "cmd /k C:\Python27\python.exe C:\Users\ashish.baboo\Desktop\UKT-SL-Ashish\Cleaning-Tools\Old-Geocode.py"
waitTill = Now() + TimeValue("00:00:40")
While Now() < waitTill
DoEvents
```

This Python script loads addresses in an excel file placed at desktop. When i run python script directly, It executes perfectly. But when i am running VBA code, Python script opens but gives me an error that excel file is not available. Here is my code of Python script:

```
 import xlrd
import geocoder
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import load_workbook
location = "C:\\Users\\ashish.baboo\\Desktop\\UKT-SL-Ashish\\Cleaning-Tools\\1.xlsx"
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(location)
sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(1)


Rows = sheet.nrows
Cols = sheet.ncols
data = [[sheet.cell_value(r,c) for c in range(Cols)] for r in range(Rows)]

wb = load_workbook('1.xlsx')
ws1 = wb.get_sheet_by_name("Locations")


for i in range(1,Rows):
    add = ws1.cell(row = i+1, column = 19).value
    cadd = geocoder.google(add  , language = "en" , key = "AIzaSyBsiH6LubuA9dn1s97UsUcesQRw71isBuo")
    print(i , cadd.latlng , cadd.quality ,cadd.country)
    S_no = ws1.cell(row = i+1, column = 1) 
    O_Housenumber = ws1.cell(row = i+1, column = 3)
    O_Street = ws1.cell(row = i+1, column = 4)
    O_City = ws1.cell(row = i+1, column = 5)
    O_County = ws1.cell(row = i+1, column = 6)
    O_State = ws1.cell(row = i+1, column = 7)
    O_Postal = ws1.cell(row = i+1, column = 8)
    O_Country = ws1.cell(row = i+1, column = 9)
    Latitude = ws1.cell(row = i+1, column = 10)
    Longitude = ws1.cell(row = i+1, column = 11)
    Accuracy = ws1.cell(row = i+1, column = 12)
    S_no.value = i
    O_Housenumber.value = cadd.housenumber
    O_Street.value = cadd.street
    O_City.value = cadd.city
    O_County.value = cadd.county
    O_State.value = cadd.state_long
    O_Postal.value = cadd.postal
    O_Country.value = cadd.country_long
    Latitude.value = cadd.lat
    Longitude.value = cadd.lng
    Accuracy.value = cadd.quality

    wb.save('1.xlsx')
```

I already tried many solutions but was not successful. Kindly suggest how to resolve it ?

Comment: is your VBA code run from the same file which python script tries to open?

Comment: @avb i did not get you . But, NO . My code is in outlook VBA. SO it is not in excel file, script is trying to open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
wb = load_workbook('1.xlsx')
```

relies on the program knowing where to look for the file. If you are firing up Python from VBA then the working directory will almost certainly be different. So your Python program needs to know the full filepath. You can either hard-code it in the program, or you can pass it in to the program from the command line.

Comment: this is the correct answer. This resolved my issue. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

use absolute path instead of relative path will do the trick!